# Could not load file or assembly 'video.player.net.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.":"video.player.net.dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, onvif

I am developing an LPR in c# windows form I use onvif to connect to camera so i added the requirement dll to my project as you can see 
[image]

My project builds successfully but when i run my project i get this error :

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'video.player.net.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.":"video.player.net.dll"}

Stack

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at nMCR.Program.Main() in E:\Symfa Files\Old Symfa\1-جدید و مشکل پرش دوربین\nMCR\nMCR\Program.cs:line 19
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Maybe it's that folder, whatever it's called: `E:\Symfa Files\Old Symfa\1-جدید و مشکل` also check you have all the dependencies using a tool DependencyWalker

Comment: @JeremyThompson Thank you finally the swscale-2.dll is missing

Comment: @JeremyThompson honestly i am waiting for your post because you answered first .So if you let me i mark the Marco post as  correct answer

Comment: My pleasure, glad you worked it out. Give the points to @Marco he needs that min 50 rep to comment. Cheers

Comment: @JeremyThompson thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The video.player.net.dll depends on some native libraries. See here the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) screen:

[image]

Ensure that also these files are accessible for the application. (Note: find in [this blogpost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463243/dll-search-on-windows) the dll search paths).

Comment: Thanks for this I'm not behind a PC, very nice answer!