# SQLLDR in instantclient_21_9 cannot run

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, instantclient

I'm a Window user and I have a problem with Oracle SQLLDR.
Whenever I run SQLLDR in CMD, it shows Errors: The code execution cannot proceed because xxx.dll was not found. It pops up several times for some xxx.dll files missing.
[image]

I have both instantclient_21_9 and ODAC122011 in my computer. ODAC122011x64 is required by PowerBI to Get data from Oracle database. And I'm still able to connect to Oracle database as well.

I have followed many instructions but they all not work to me. Then I really need your help here.
I have download:

- instantclient-basic-windows.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip
- instantclient-sqlplus-windows.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip
- instantclient-tools-windows.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip

from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html
and extract them all in the same directory
I have set PATH in System Variable as below
[image: PATH]

The ODAC122011\product\12.2.0\client_1 must be above for PowerBI getting data from Oracle Database

I have also tried to remove ODAC from PATH to test, but it's still the same error:

[image]

Comment: PATH is used only to resolve execution paths (e.g. find the sqlldr program). Your error is about a DLL. Look into whether you have LD_LIBRARY_PATH properly set (it should include $ORACLE_HOME/lib) which is where DLLs are looked for.

Comment: @PaulW https://stackoverflow.com/q/2463243/11107541

Comment: I'm a Unix-only guy, if it's different on Windows, it's different. But the error is coming from something not set so that it can find the libraries. On Unix, that's LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: You have both the full 12.2 client under ODAC and 21.9 Instant Client in your path.  This could be a cause of library clashes.  Do a quick test after removing the ODAC libraries from PATH.  (P.S. there's nothing executable in the network/admin subdir, and this subdir should not be in PATH)

Comment: According to this discussion this may be a known bug. Check with Oracle Support for a patch. (https://community.oracle.com/mosc/discussion/4518059/sqlldr-error-oranl-dll-and-others-missing)

Comment: @pmdba: I cannot open the link "Oops! Access Denied". Do they fix the error?

Comment: @ChristopherJones I have removed ODAC from the PATH and restarted the computer, but nothing change. I will update the test in the post. Moreover, I find this on internet and I also think it's not about .dll files, but still cannot find how to fix it.

Comment: @VietAnhNguyen Apologies: You may need an account in the Oracle Communities to read the post. They're free. If you're going to spend time with Oracle technologies, I'd advise you to sign up as another source of specialized community knowledge. It sounds like the bug was first reported a year ago, so they may not have fixed it yet, or there may be a patch required to the baseline release. You'd have to contact Oracle Support to find out.

Comment: @VietAnhNguyen The link says to use 19c for the moment.